# Automate code deploy from Git lab to AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, gitlab

We're building an application for which we are using ***GitLab*** repository. Manual deployment of code to the test server which is **Amazon AWS EC2 instance** is tedious, I'm planning to automate deployment process, such that when we commit code, it should reflect in the test instance.

from my knowledge we can use **AWS code-deploy** service to fetch the code from **GitHub.** But ***code deploy service does not support GitLab repository .*** Is there a way to automate the code deployment process to AWS Ec2 instance through GitLab. or Is there a shell scripting possibility to achieve this? Kindly educate me.

Comment: Have you looked into using a CI server like Jenkins or Team City? That could build your code on commit and then kick off a script to perform the deployment.

Comment: Hi Mark, 
After your suggestion I happen to check for those CI servers, for using any of those we need to write our shell script that will initiate the automatic deployment of code right? so jenkins/teamcity uses our script to perform deployment ? is my understanding right?

Comment: Yes it would trigger your deploy script. Or it could trigger AWS Code Deploy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way you could achieve this with AWS CodeDeploy is by using the S3 option in conjunction with Gitlab-CI: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/getting-started-w.html

Depending on how your project is setup, you may have the possibility to generate a distribution Zip (Gradle offers this through the application plugin). You may need to generate your "distribution" file manually if your project does not offer such a capability.

Gitlab does not offer a direct S3 integration, however through the `gitlab-ci.yml` you would be able to download it into the container and run the necessary upload commands to put the generated zip file on the S3 container as per the AWS instructions to trigger the deployment.

Here is an example of what your `brefore-script` could look like in the `gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
before_script:
  - apt-get update --quiet --yes
  - apt-get --quiet install --yes python
  - pip install -U pip
  - pip install awscli
```

The AWS tutorial on how to use CodeDeploy with S3 is very detailed, so I will skip attempting to reproduce the contents here.

In regards to the actual deployment commands and actions that you are currently performing manually, AWS CodeDeploy provides the capability to run certain actions through scripts defined in the app-spec file depending on event hooks for the application:

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/writing-app-spec.html
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/app-spec-ref.html
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/app-spec-ref-hooks.html

I hope this helps.

Comment: It helps. Thanks. Its just scary to see how deeply we are integrating with a platform like AWS.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of my old post. But I happened to find an answer for this. Although my question is specific to work with code deploy I would say there is no such need to use any aws requirements using gitlab.

We don't require Code Deploy at all. There is no need to use any external CI server like the team city or the jenkins to perform the CI from the GitLab anymore.

We need to add the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file in the source directory of the branch and write an .yml script in it. There are pipelines in the GitLab that will perform the CI/CD automatically.

The pipelines of the GitLab CI/CD looks more similar to the working functionality of Jenkins Server. using the YML script we can perform SSH on the EC2 instance and place the files in it.

An example of how to write the gitlab .yml file to ssh to ec2 instance is here https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html